# How do I get my game made?

Tags: game-design

So, I have the idea, the concept, and know how I want to market my game... so now what? The game that I have designed is to vast to create alone, but I know that it can work. I need a large team, but I dunno how or where to get one, or how to go about this. I understand code enough to know if something can work properly, but not enough to actually make the game myself, and I am not skilled with creating art, but I know how I want things to look. What do I do? Clearly, as I have asked before, a big game company won't hire me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**You pay people.**

If you don't have the skills or the person-hours capacity to execute on your vision alone, then you need other people to provide that labour. That labour has value, so they need to be compensated, both as a moral imperative, but also for practicality: they need the means to feed, house, and clothe themselves and their families over the potentially many years of work it takes to build a large game.

They can't do that just on the promise of a share of future profits when the game releases and (hopefully) sells millions. No developer with any experience would take such a gamble, knowing that the large majority of games never turn a profit (even ones based on amazing ideas the creators were certain would succeed). And it would be exploitation to take advantage of inexperienced creators who don't yet understand these risks.

For a single skilled programmer, that can easily run into hundreds of thousands of dollars per year, plus benefits. So unless you're heir to a large fortune or the winner of a big lottery payout / investment windfall, it's not something you'll be able to fund alone.

So you'd probably need investors - venture capital, crowdfunding, government arts grants, etc. Here the challenge is that to invest in your proposal, these folks will expect to see evidence that you can accomplish what you claim. Without a portfolio of past successful games, that's going to be a difficult sell.

Beware of "get rich quick" schemes like cryptocurrency "initial coin offerings" as ways to raise capital - this area is rife with scams and bad actors, and consumers are rightfully becoming wary of them.

---

So, if you don't have/can't immediately get the money to fund such a project, what do you do?

**Accept that this game will not be made.**

**...at least, not *yet***.

Be willing to put this idea on the shelf for now. You can keep revisiting and polishing it every so often, until the time is right. It will wait for you.

Many game creators who eventually release their magnum opus describe it as something they had in mind for years, even decades, before the stars aligned in such a way that they could finally execute on it. Often, the idea grew and shifted with them as they developed as creators and the market evolved in the meantime, so what was eventually a success might not have been so successful, had they been able to run with their first idea when they originally thought of it.

Your first game will not be your dream game. Expect to work up to it gradually, making smaller games to build your skills, experience, and resources; or spending years contributing to others' games as just one collaborator in a team, until you develop the seniority, connections, and clout to help steer large projects.

I'm 15 years into my professional game development career, spanning roles in indie, AAA, and academia, and I still haven't made something I could call "my dream game". But I've nevertheless been able to earn a comfortable living doing a job I enjoy, and made games of which I'm fiercely proud, and I feel joy whenever I see folks play them, or hear heartfelt feedback from fans. Along the way, the games I dream of have changed more than once, and I'm still keeping notes and doing experiments that may one day culminate in a dream game, or find their way to be expressed in some form in the games I work on in the meantime.

[Ze Frank's "Invocation for Beginnings"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RYlCVwxoL_g) has a couple lines that have always stuck with me:

> Let me not think of my work only as a stepping stone to something else, and if it is, **let me become fascinated by the shape of the stone.**
>
> Let me take the idea that has gotten me this far and put it to bed.  What I am about to do will not be that, But it will be something.

Find something to love in everything you make, and it won't sting so much that you're not able to immediately make the thing you love most.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed to know! thank you so much! its a shame though, my game might not be relevant anymore in a few years. It was supposed to be this awesome heist-based open world game where everything you do matters in one way or another.

Comment: I feel your pain. I've worked on a few games that missed their window of opportunity and never got the chance to shine that they deserved. But I learned something from working on and thinking about every one of them, and I can take those learnings forward to make my *next* games better, even if they're not the same idea.

Comment: @Joshua well the other option is to find people who are just as excited about your idea as you are - but you won't, unless your idea is really good.

Comment: @Joshua you might consider lowering your expectations until you get to something you *can* make. Let's say you want to make Minecraft and you can't... then, well, could you make Minecraft classic creative mode? Could you make Motherlode?

Comment: @Joshua if you really like the idea of "everything affecting everything else" then you might consider making something along the lines of [Until Dawn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Until_Dawn). Of course, you don't need the pre-rendered movie quality of that game. Or maybe something along the lines of [House](https://store.steampowered.com/app/1444350/House/). Look up a let's play of either one and consider how you feel about it. Neither is open world, nor about heists, but they basically both concentrate on the player figuring out unpredictable effects.

Answer (score 6):

I see a couple of options:

- Produce a full game design document and take out your wallet: there are companies out there that will produce a game for you, but you'll need to pay them. The good news is that you have the final word on what the game will look like, the bad news is that you take all the risk, because you'll be the one taking the money out of your pocket, not them.
- Reduce the scope of your project and start learning more aspects of game development, programming, art, audio, and start working on your game. You can then hit the recruitment section some web sites to try and have people come on board ([GDNet](https://www.gamedev.net/forums/forum/29-hobby-project-classifieds/) comes to mind).
- Reduce the scope of your project, and start a degree in game development, then for the final project, hope your team wishes to produce your idea.
- Reduce the scope of your project and start learning more aspects of game development, programming, art, audio, and start working on your game. Work at another place to get money and pay a freelancer to have them produce the aspects of the development you're having more trouble with.
- Reduce the scope of your project to a point where it completely fits within your field of expertise, and release the game by yourself.

I understand that "Reduce the scope of your project" is there often. You need to keep a couple things in mind:

- making games is hard
- those who have never worked on a game can work for free for a time
- people working for free may, at some point, feel exploited, so they'll either tire out and stop working for you because they don't get anything in return (it's *your* pet project, not theirs), or they'll turn into freelancers
- freelancers don't work for free as working for you is their living, so you'll need to pay them.

Comment: I appreciate the emphasis on "reduce the scope of your project" here. Excessive scope is probably the #1 killer of even great game projects. A small, but tight, well-executed game is a foundation you can build on with expansions/etc., eventually growing its scope. But a project that's too ambitious to successfully finish its initial release will never see the light of day.